# what is difference between less and cat with respect to reading binary files?

Tags: logs, cat, less

While I'm trying to read the file `/var/log/boot.log` with `less`, I will get the this message:

```bsh
[amirreza@localhost ~]$ sudo less /var/log/boot.log
"/var/log/boot.log" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

But when I try it using `cat`, the result is a colored text file, something like this:

```bsh
         Starting Virtualization daemon...
         Starting Notify NFS peers of a restart...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Finished Permit User Sessions.
[  OK  ] Started Deferred execution scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started Command Scheduler.
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[  OK  ] Started Notify NFS peers of a restart.
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

I know systemd saves it logs in binary format and we need special tools to inspect them but what is the difference between `less` and `cat` ?

Comment: Use `less -fR /var/log/boot.log` if you're sure that's a file `less` can handle. `less` is able to display binary files (it will show non-printable chars in hex form or in caret form) but has serious problems with files with very long lines (as binary files tend to be if naively treated as text files), so that confirmation is supposed to be *helpful*.

Comment: You can see what can happen when `less` tries to display a binary file with: `dd if=big_sparse seek=2G count=0` followed by `less big_sparse`. If you answer "yes" to "See it anyway?", `less` will try to eat up all the available memory, which may result in your terminal emulator and GUI being ejected to swap, and your system becoming unresponsive if you're not pressing Control-C quick enough ;-) `less` has the same problem with very large single-line xml files, but those weren't yet fashionable at the time `less` was developed, so `less` won't ask you any questions in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`less` looks into the file before showing it, and if it thinks it's a binary file, it asks, on the assumption that you might not want to see garbage like this:

```
<BB>!^@h^C^@^@^@<E9><B0><FF><FF><FF><FF>%^B<BB>!^@h^D^@^@^@
<E9><A0><FF><FF><FF><FF>%<FA><BA>!^@h^E^@^@^@<E9><90><FF><FF>
<FF><FF>%<F2><BA>!^@h^F^@^@^@<E9><80><FF><FF><FF><FF>%<EA>
<BA>!^@h^G^@^@^@<E9>p^@^@^@<E9>@<FF><FF><FF><FF>%ʺ!^@h^K^@^@
```

That's what `less /bin/ls` shows on my system, `<BB>`, `^F` and `^@` being various representations for nonprintable characters. By default it shows control characters like that, instead of sending them to the terminal, which might have unwanted consequences.

The odd thing here is that `less` actually has support for ANSI color escape sequences, in that it with the `-R` flag it sends those to the terminal, but suppresses other control characters. And if your log file only contains color escapes codes, it probably shouldn't think of it as a binary file.

On the other hand, `cat` just dumps the raw data to the terminal, and doesn't care at all what happens. Depending on the contents of the file, it may e.g. change your terminal font to line drawing characters.

Answer (score -1):

cat basically dumps any input (including stdin) on the screen without processing it in any way.

less is a paginator i.e. it's intended to work with text files.